# What is the difference between drop.levels(x) in the gdata package and as.factor(as.character(x))?

Tags: r, gdata

as question, as I can see the speed is higher for the later method, why use the first one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two command does quite the same but not exactly, especially when you have the preserve the original order of the factors. **In some cases you cannot use:** `as.factor(as.character(f))`. See:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
f <- factor(c("D", "B", "C", "K", "A"), levels=c("K", "B", "C", "D"))[2:4]
plot(f, main="Original factor")
f.fc <- as.factor(as.character(f))
plot(f.fc, main="as.factor(as.character(f))")
f.d <- drop.levels(f)
plot(f.d, main="drop.levels(f)")
f.d <- drop.levels(f, reorder=FALSE)
plot(f.d, main="drop.levels(f, reorder=FALSE))")
f.f <- factor(f)
plot(f.f, main="factor(f)")
```

[image]

`as.factor(as.character(f))` and `drop.levels(f)` does the same and they do not preserve the original order of factors, they both re-level the text in ABC order. I you want to preserve the order you can use the `reorder=FALSE` option in `drop.levels()`.

This is the default behavior of `factor()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to drop unused levels, all you need to do is:

```
x <- factor(x)
```

Comment: so factor(x) is equivalent to as.factor(as.character(x))?

Comment: Yes, factor(x) will have the same result.

Comment: @lokheart: I think they will not have the same result if you have to preserve the order of your factors.

Answer (score 2):

New in R (from version 2.12.0) is the function `droplevels()` to do the same thing. It is implemented as:

```
> base:::droplevels.factor
function (x, ...) 
factor(x)
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So I would use that function out of preference. It is a generic function in R with methods for objects of class `"factor"` and `"data.frame"`, the latter is useful when there are many factors in the data frame that need levels dropping.